# use a string as a parameter in a equation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to use a string as a parameter in an equation to get a value from another tab.

For example, i want to use the string 'OKT' in the gray column as a reference inside the equation in the orange column. Is this possible?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `indirect()`, like this:

`=indirect(A8 & "!L29")`